# jquery window on load not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload-event

I'm using jquery to toggle a loader animation on page load: when the page (text and images) is loading, the div containing the loader animation is shown over the page. When the page is fully loaded the div with the loader is toggled off.

```
<div class="loader">
    <div class="cssload-speeding-wheel"></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('load',function() {
        $('.loader').hide();
    });

    // Other things...
});
```

and this works for the first time you open the page, but at the second time, when images are already cached the $(window).on('load', ...) is not execued (I guess because images are loaded faster before document.ready) and consequently the loader is not toggled off.

P.S. I noticed this while testing on Android with Chrome, on my PC this problem is not showing

Does anyone have an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: this is because the first time you visit a webpage your browser saves the images till you close it. The next time you open the page the images will be already loaded.

Comment: I've tested on chrome Iphone and it works, did you check that document ready is called and window load not calledby some alert or console.log?

Comment: When `$(document).ready()` is fired `$(window).on('load')` already was fired. Take the second event out of `.ready()`.

Comment: yeah he is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with this code

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){


    // Other things...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to use:

````
    $('.loader').hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){


    // Other things...
});```
````